# rails if statement according to check box

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, if-statement, checkbox

I am working on a user adding page. In form, there is a check box which you can choose admin or developer. And then you are choosing a company for new user from a list. And the company can be a reseller or not. Developers must belong to resellers only and non-admin-non-developer users must belong to non-resellers. How can I do this? 
Here is my user.rb :

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :email, :name, :password, :password_confirmation, :developer, :admin, :company_id, :boss_id
    has_many :sent_configuration, :class_name => 'Conf', :foreign_key => 'developer_id', :dependent => :destroy
    has_many :received_configuration, :class_name => 'Conf', :foreign_key => 'user_id'
    belongs_to :company
    has_secure_password

    before_save { |user| user.email = email.downcase }
    before_save :create_token

    validates :company_id, presence: true
    validates :name,  presence: true, length: { maximum:50 }

    VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
    validates :email, presence: true, 
                format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }

    validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }
    validates :password_confirmation, presence: true

    private 
    def create_token
       self.token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
    end
end
```

This is my newuser.html.erb :

```
<% provide(:title, 'Invite') %>
<h1>Invite new user</h1>

<div class="row">
  <div class="span6 offset3">
    <%= form_for @user do |f| %>

      <%= render '/shared/error_messages' %>

      <%= f.label :name %>
      <%= f.text_field :name %>

      <%= f.label :email %>
      <%= f.text_field :email %>

      <% if current_user.admin? %>

      <%= f.label :developer %>
      <%= f.check_box :developer %>

      <br /><br />

      <%= f.label :admin %>
      <%= f.check_box :admin %>


      <% end %>

      <br /><br />

      <%= f.label :company_id %>
      <%= f.collection_select :company_id, Company.all , :id, :name_for_form, {:prompt => 'Please select the company of this user'}  %>


      <%= f.label :password %>
      <%= f.password_field :password %>

      <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirmation" %>
      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>

      <%= f.submit "Invite new user", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>

    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

And this is my users_controller.rb :

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter  :signed_in_user, only:[:index, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_filter  :correct_user,   only:[:edit, :update]
  before_filter  :admin_user,     only: :destroy

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def newuser
@user = User.new
  end

  def create
@user = User.new(params[:user])

 if @user.save
    #sign_in @user
    flash[:success] = "Welcome to the ManusWeb!"
      redirect_to @user
 else
      render 'newuser'
 end
end

def index
@users = User.where(:developer => false).paginate(page: params[:page])

respond_to do |format|
  format.html #index.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @users }
  format.xml { render xml: @users }  
end
end

def developers
   @users = User.where(:developer => true).paginate(page: params[:page])
end

def clients
  @users = User.where(:boss_id => current_user.id).paginate(page: params[:page])
end

def update

  if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
    # Handle a successful update.
    flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
    sign_in @user
    redirect_to @user
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end

def destroy
  User.find(params[:id]).destroy
  flash[:success] = "User deleted"
  redirect_to users_url
end

def client
  ( !current_user.admin? && !current_user.developer? )
end

private
  def signed_in_user
    unless signed_in?
      store_location
      redirect_to signin_url, notice: "Please sign in"    
    end
  end
  def correct_user
    @user = User.find(params[:id])  
    redirect_to root_url, notice: "You are not authorized to request this page"  unless current_user?(@user)
  end

  def admin_user
    redirect_to(root_path) unless current_user.admin?  
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you should create some validations in the User model. Let's say you have a reseller flag in you company model, then add something like:

```
validates :developer, :developer => true   if self.company.reseller
validates :developer, :developer => false  if !self.company.reseller && !self.admin
```

then, to have your views working, you might want to use some good old javascript, because your conditions (`<% if current_user.admin? %>`) on the user's role in *newuser.html.erb* are static, they get evaluated only when the page is rendered.

With javascript, you can attach a function on the click event for the checkboxes, something like (in coffeescript):

```
$ '#your_checkbox_id').on('click', (event) ->
    if checked show just the resellers else show all the companies (pseudocode)
```

and that would do.
Sorry if I didn't give all the code for it, but it's not a 5-minute job... hope it can help.

Comment: thanks, but I dont know javascript, can you at least give me some links to start searching? I even dont know what to write to google

Comment: Also my User model has company_id and your validation codes give error. It says, undefined method company. My Company model has a boolean named reseller, is this flag?

Comment: Ok: - a flag is a boolean variable/attribute, so yes, your reseller boolean is a flag

Comment: - make sure your company model contains a `has_may :user`

Comment: - if you are new to javascript, it might take you a while. This is a good starting point: http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp.

Comment: my company already has 'has_many :users'. and i have not much time to learn javascript from zero.